# How to know whether the function is integrable or not

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to integrate $$\int e^{x^2}dx$$
I tried using product rule and saw that this will form an infinite series.

Now I have two questions

> 1. How to integrate this function?
>
> 2.If this is not integrable, then I have some more questions which are behaving same or not being solved by me . How can I know those function are integrable or not?

Comment: Gaussian  integral.....;.

Comment: Be careful with terminology. This function *is* integrable. But it has no closed-form antiderivative.

Comment: "I have some more questions which are behaving same or not being solved by me": could you turn this in an English sentence, please ?

Answer (score 3):

The function $e^{x^2}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ so it is **integrable** in the sense that the definite integral
$$\int_a^b e^{x^2} \,\mbox{d}x$$
exists for all real numbers $a,b$. The *fundamental theorem of calculus* also guarantees the existence of a primitive function (anti-derivative) of $e^{x^2}$.

But what you may be looking for is a closed form, **elementary anti-derivative**. That does not exist for $e^{x^2}$ so you'll either need to work with series or 'hide' the problem by using special functions such as the (Gauss) error function.

> (...) but does there exists any function which are not integrable??

If you're looking for a function that isn't (Riemann) integrable, then this is a classic example:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
        1 &\text{if } x\in \mathbb Q \\
        0 & \text{if } x\notin \mathbb Q
\end{cases}$$

Comment: But how do you know there isn’t a closed form, elementary anti-derivative?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of *known* functions a primitive for your integral can be written in terms of the so-called [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function) $\text{erfi} (x)$. Defined as
$$\text{erfi} (x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{t^2} \, dt,$$
we see that
$$\int e^{x^2} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{erfi} (x) + C.$$

Note that despite the name *imaginary error function*, $\text{erfi}⁡ (x)$ is real when $x$ is real.

Answer (score 0):

It's integrable but the only way you can express this easily is
$$
F\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!\left(2n+1\right)}
$$

Comment: Yes exactly, but does there exists any function which are not integrable??

Comment: Heaviside function ?